# SQL Redshift - Issue to join two tables

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have an issue with a JOIN clause on SQL Redshift. There are two tables I want to join :

Table_1

```
id  country  x
1   fr       10
2   fr       20
3   fr       30
```

Table_2

```
id  country  y
1   fr       80
2   gb       40
3   gb       60
4   fr       90
```

I would like to have a final table as this :

```
id  country  x     y
1   fr       10    80
2   fr       20    NULL
2   gb       NULL  40
3   fr       30    NULL
3   gb       NULL  60
4   fr       NULL  90
```

Could anyone tell me how I can solve this problem ?
Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution :

```
select COALESCE(table_1.id, table_2.id) AS id
       ,COALESCE(table_1.country, table_2.country) AS country
       ,x
       ,y
from table_1
    full outer join table_2 on table_1.id = table_2.id
                           and table_1.country = table_2.country
order by 1
         ,2
;
```